# Getting an ajax response in java from a web method (java.io.FileNotFoundException)

Tags: java, android, ajax, httpurlconnection

Don't know how to explain it better but i'm trying to get a response from an URL containing a function (right?).

I'm working on this for a lot of hours and progressing a little every time but can't get this finally working.
This is the request and response headers from chrome dev tools:

[Headers](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/13/headersl.jpg/)

My code is:

```
String params = "{\"prefixText\":\"" + city 
                    + "\",\"count\":10,\"contextKey\":\"he\"}";
conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(
        "http://bus.gov.il/WebForms/wfrmMain.aspx/GetCompletionList")
        .openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
// conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(params.length());
conn.addRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(params.length()));
conn.addRequestProperty("Host", "bus.gov.il");
conn.addRequestProperty("Origin", "http://bus.gov.il");
conn.addRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
conn.addRequestProperty("Referer",
        "http://bus.gov.il/WebForms/wfrmMain.aspx?width=1024&company=1&language=he&state=");
OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
os.write(params.getBytes());
String answer = readStream(conn.getInputStream());
```

I get the exception (I see in the stack trace) when calling "getinputstream" on this line:

`String answer = readStream(conn.getInputStream());`

before entering the readStream function!

I don't know how to solve it...

Tried searching about xmlhttprequest but understood that it's only in JS.

Also: I know I have a lot of unnecessary request properties but I can't figure out which are unnecessary until the code will work.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Working code if anyone needs:
http://pastebin.com/kFZwA5zR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, it used to be (and probably still is) that the HttpURLConnection throws a FileNotFoundException when you get a 404 error. When you are doing the getInputStream() that's when it's first connecting, so any error from the server will show up there.

Get Wireshark or something if you want to see what's really going on in HTTP land as you make the request.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Wireshark tip!
I made it work (the problem was that the requset body was sent not as applicaton/json and the writing wasn't good too).
Now I have another problem, the two request bodies sent by me (one from the browser and one from eclipse) are encoded differently for some reason... 
I tried changing the content-type charset but didn't solve it.

Comment: Sorry... didn't finish my comment and can't edit it..

Thanks a lot for the Wireshark tip!
I made it work (the problem was that the requset body was sent not as applicaton/json and the writing wasn't good too).
Now I have another problem, the two request bodies sent by me (one from the chrome browser and one from eclipse) are encoded differently for some reason... 
I tried changing the content-type charset but didn't solve it.

Here is the compared two requests (first is good, second isn't):
[link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/59/chromeeclipse.jpg/)
(look at the "prefixText" key)

Comment: You should make a different question for that, since that issue is not related to this question (it will help the next person who looks this up). I don't know the answer off the top of my head, but I will look at your new question when you post it.