# HTTP Post request bodies differently encoded (charset)

Tags: java, android, http, character-encoding, request

Reference to previous question: [Getting an ajax response in java from a web method (java.io.FileNotFoundException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639068/getting-an-ajax-response-in-java-from-a-web-method-java-io-filenotfoundexceptio)

I try to send a POST request containing json in the request body but the body is encoded differently when doing it from a web browser (chrome) and my java code.
Here is my code:

```
String params = "{\"prefixText\":\"aCity\",\"count\":10,\"contextKey\":\"he\"}";
conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://bus.gov.il/WebForms/wfrmMain.aspx/GetCompletionList").openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(params.length());
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "http://bus.gov.il/WebForms/wfrmMain.aspx?width=1024&company=1&language=he&state=");
Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()));
out.write(params);
out.close();
String answer = readStream(conn.getInputStream(), "utf-8");
```

Here are the 2 requests sent as seen in Wireshark: [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/59/chromeeclipse.jpg/) (first is the good one, second is the wrongly encoded java request).

I tried changing the charset in Content-Type but it did nothing.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you're using the default character encoding for your system:

```
Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()));
```

Instead, specify the encoding explicitly in the constructor call for `OutputStreamWriter`:

```
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
```

(You don't need the `BufferedWriter` here - it's not doing you any good.)

EDIT: Okay, you're now getting a problem because you're setting the content length incorrectly. You should convert from text to binary *once*, like this:

```
byte[] data = params.getBytes("UTF-8");
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(data.length);
...
OutputStream output = conn.getOutputStream();
// Note: you should use a finally block here
output.write(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it doesn't write at all to the stream.
It says `java.io.IOException: too many bytes written`

Comment: @RonLut: Right, that's because you've used the length of the string in *characters* as the length, instead of the length of the encoded string in *bytes*. Will edit.

Comment: NVM, got it by myself a minute before you posted.
Changed to: `conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);` and now it works.
Thanks again :)

Comment: @RonLut: You can do that, but you don't have to. See my edit.

Comment: 1. Shouldn't output stream be buffered?
2. You mean write should be in finally block? why?

Comment: @RonLut: Why would you want to buffer such a small output stream? About the finally block: you should always close streams in a finally block, so that they end up being closed even if there's an exception while you're using the stream.